# C# Inherited member variables behaving undexpectedly

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, variables, member

If I have a class like this:

```
class A {
    public string fe = "A";
}
```

And a class that inherits from it like so:

```
class B : A {
    public string fe = "B";
}
```

Visual C# will tell me that B.fe hides A.fe so I should use the new keyword. So I change class B to look like:

```
class B : A {
    public new string fe = "B";
}
```

And then I have a function that takes an A (but, by virtue of inheritance, will also take a B) like this:

```
class D {
    public static void blah(A anAObject) {
        Console.Writeline(A.fe);
    }
}
```

Even when I pass it an instance of a B object, which it will take without question, it will print "A"! Why is this, and how can I make it work how I want without setting the variable in the constructor?

Comment: Question says C++; tags say C#. Which is it?

Comment: I don't see where it says C++. And if this was C++, there would be a ; at the closing bracket of my classes ;D

Comment: Third paragraph, non-code block: "Visual C++ will tell me that B.fe hides A.fe so I should use the new keyword. So I change class B to look like:"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the difference between `override` and `new`. `new` defines a member which happens to have the same name as a member in the base class. It doesn't override that member. So if you have a method that expects an `A` instance, it will take the value of `A.fe` and not the member in the derived class with the same name.

Use a property with `override` instead:

```
class A {
    public virtual string fe { get { return "A"; } }
}

class B : A {
    public override string fe { get { return "B"; } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed to know. I'm going to assume it doesn't have to be a property though.

Comment: @Nilbert: You can't override fields -- that wouldn't make sense. So you have to use a property (or a method).

Comment: Oh ok, thanks very much. This will be marked the answer when the timer lets me do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your `fe` member to be overridable by derived classes without having to use the `new` keyword (which is why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing), just declare it `virtual` in the base class. Then your code would look like this:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string fe
    {
        get { return "A"; }
    }
}

public class B
{
    public override string fe
    {
        get { return "B"; }
    }
}
```

Notice that this required making `fe` a **property**, since member fields cannot be declared `virtual`.

The explanation for why you're not getting the behavior you want is that the `new` keyword only overrides an inherited member in the event that a variable is declared as the derived class at compile time. If it's declared as the base class at compile time (as `anAObject` is in your `blah` method), it goes with the base class version (this is what differentiates `new` from `override`).

Now, you also *could* modify your `blah` method to cast its input to a `B`, thereby accessing your `new` `fe`:

```
public static void blah(A anAObject) {
    var aBObject = anAObject as B;
    if (aBObject != null)
        Console.WriteLine(aBObject.fe); // would print "B"
    else
        Console.WriteLine(anAObject.fe); // would print "A"
}
```

But I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {

public virtual string fe { get { return "A"; } set {} }

}

class B {
 public override string fe { get { return "B"; } set {} }
}
```

is what you need...

AFAIK in the `D.blah()` the object is getting cast of type `A` & since the base value is not marked with the `virtual` keyword, it would behave as `A` & not as `B` even if the type is `B`...